# why is a diagonal element of a matrix greater than its determinant divided by the complementary principal minor?

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse

In this paper by Fiedler (1964) : "RELATIONS BETWEEN THE DIAGONAL ELEMENTS OF TWO MUTUALLY INVERSE POSITIVE DEFINITE MATRICES",

it is written in the proof of Theorem (3.2) on page 6 that $a_{ii}A_{ii} \geq det(A)$ is well-known.

[image: Page 6 of the paper]

Can someone indicate me where this comes from? I've searched for two hours but must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality $a_{ii}\alpha_{ii}\ge1$ follows from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$
\begin{align}
a_{ii}\alpha_{ii}
=(e_i^\ast Ae_i)(e_i^\ast A^{-1}e_i)
&=\|A^{1/2}e_i\|^2\|A^{-1/2}e_i\|^2\tag{$\dagger$}\\
&\ge|\langle A^{1/2}e_i, A^{-1/2}e_i\rangle|^2\\
&=|\langle e_i, A^{1/2}A^{-1/2}e_i\rangle|^2
=1.
\end{align}
$$
To be honest, I am not sure if the same inequality in the form of $a_{ii}A_{ii}\ge\det(A)$ is really well-known, but it certainly follows easily from the use of [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement). Let $A=\pmatrix{a_{11}&v^\ast\\ v&P}$. Then
$$
\det(A)=\det(P)(a_{11}-v^\ast P^{-1}v)\le a_{11}\det(P)=a_{11}A_{11}.
$$
*Remark on the paper's remark*. Equality holds in $(\dagger)$ if and only if $A^{-1/2}e_i$ is a nonnegative scalar multiple of $A^{1/2}e_i$, i.e., iff $e_i$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to a nonnegative eigenvalue. Since $A$ is positive definite, this simply means $e_i$ is an eigenvector of $A$, i.e., all off-diagonal elements on the $i$-th row and column of $A$ are zero.

Comment: Oh thanks! Ok, so these two proofs are really specific to symmetric positive definite matrices. If A is positive definite but non-symmetric, would this be adaptable ? And if A is not even positive definite, but a $P$-matrix, i.e. all principal minors are strictly positive, is there any chance to prove that $\alpha_{ii} \geq 1$ if $a_{ii} = 1$ for all $i$?

Comment: @user20638 No. Consider $A=\pmatrix{1&-2\\ 1&1}$, which is a P-matrix with a positive definite symmetric part and a diagonal of ones.

Comment: Nice. And what if the non-diagonal terms are all in $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: @user20638 Still no. Consider $A=\pmatrix{1&1/2&0\\ 0&1&1/2\\ 1/2&0&1}$ for instance.

Comment: Wow, thanks. This matrix is also postivie definite so it answers all my questions. How do you come up so easily with counterexamples?

Comment: @user20638 I did not notice your requirement that the non-diagonal entries are $\ge0$, although I noticed that you wanted them to be smaller than $1$. So, I initially considered $A=I_3+K$ for some nonzero skew-symmetric matrix $K$. Every such $K$ with $|k_{ij}|\le1$ would produce a counterexample $A$. But then I noticed that you also wanted $a_{ij}\ge0$ and I had to modify $K$ to something else. I needed a matrix $K$ from which I could immediately read off the eigenvalues, and (scalar multiples of) permutation matrices came to mind.